# Azure DevOps - Release Pipeline for TDS Project

Tags: azure, tds

I have created `Azure DevOps CI` in `Azure DevOps. That CI is generating a TDS WebDeploy Package as an artifact. Now I need to create a release pipeline to Deploy and install the items in TDS to Azure Virtual Machine.
Can anybody please suggest a recommended/ preferable way to do that?

The artifact generated also has a PowerShell script to publish it but it needs a `publishsettings` file for deploying. Please suggest how to generate a `publishsettings` file for Azure VM, if the suggested way is to deploy TDS package using that PowerShell script.

Comment: There is an official link from Hedgehog that shows you how to build and release a TDS WDP package using Azure DevOps.
https://www.teamdevelopmentforsitecore.com/Blog/TDS-5-8-Configuring-Release-Pipelines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to deploy a WebDeploy Package creted from TDS on IaaS Environment you need to setup [Web Deploy](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy) on your target server.

After WebDeploy is setup you can either use the powershell explicitly on the target server . For example:

```
.\PublishWebDeploy.ps1 -PackagePath .\HHogSSSS.Master.wdp.zip -ComputerName MyServer 
    -Username DeployUser -Password MyPassword -SiteName MySite -AuthType Basic 
    -MSDeployAllowUntrusted -ViewLogs
```

Or you can generate the required `.publishsettings` during the WebDeploy installation on the machine itself.

This is covered in more details in the [TDS Documentation Chapter 6](https://hedgehogdevelopment.github.io/tds/chapter7.html#iaas-or-standalone-deployments) in the `IaaS or Standalone deployments` section (also including some of the problems that you might encounter during the installation of Web Deploy)